# Can adhoc interface connect to AP mode interface?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

In IEEE 802.11, is it possible for an adhoc mode interface to connect to an interface in AP (infrastructure) mode?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that would work, the protocols should be different enough to prevent it. If you have two computers with a WLAN interface each, why don't you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer = no

Ad hoc mode:

An Ad-hoc network allows each device to communicate directly with each other. There is no central Access Point controlling device communication. Ad-hoc networks are only able to communicate with other Ad-hoc devices, they are not able to communicate with any Infrastructure devices or any other devices connected to a wired network.

Infrastructure mode:

An Infrastructure mode network requires the use of an Access Point. The Access Point controls Wireless communication and offers several important advantages over an Ad-hoc network. For example, a Infrastructure based network supports increased levels of security, synchronized communication through beacon intervals, potentially faster data transmission speeds and integration with a wired network.